# System of ODEs tricky equilibrium expression!

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of ODEs that I am trying to find the equilibrium points to. I firstly begin by taking (2) and rearranging for $x$. I then insert this into (3) to find a relation for $z$. Then my strategy is to insert the newly found expressions for $x$ and $z$ into $(1)$ to generate an expression for $y$. However when I do this, everything cancels and I cannot generate my expression for $y$.

Where am I going wrong?

\begin{align}
(1) \qquad \frac{dx}{dt} &= -\beta x(y + z) + \gamma y +  \alpha z + \epsilon\eta '(1-\phi)y \\
(2) \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} &= \beta yx - \gamma y - \eta \epsilon y \\
(3) \qquad \frac{dz}{dt} &= \beta zx - \alpha z + \epsilon\eta \phi  y 
\end{align}

The expression for $x$ is:

$$
x^* = \frac{1}{\beta}(\gamma + \eta\epsilon)
$$

The expression for $z^*$ is:

$$
 z = -  \frac{\epsilon \eta\phi}{\gamma + \eta\epsilon - \alpha } y 
$$

Inserting these into (1) cancels everything out and I cannot obtain an independent expression for $y^*$! I am struggling to complete further analysis without this crucial step!

Comment: Everything cancels in all three equations regardless of the value of $y^*$? In that case you have a whole line of equilibria, which is not that unusual of a situation.

Comment: Yes there are many non-isolated equilibria in this system. I see another with $(x^*,0,0)$.

Comment: Noticed that $y = 0$ was a solution of the (2) equation and that $y$ and $z$ always appear in terms.

Comment: And no its possible that non-isolated equilibria are stable. You can have all solutions approach a line, it just now happens that the initial conditions determine where on the line they end up.

Comment: You are missing two critical points and I agree with the third you found. The two missing CPs are $$x = \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}, y = 0, ~\mbox{and}~ y = 0, z = 0$$

Comment: Yes, no system has a guarantee that isolated fixed points will be obtained consider

\begin{align}
\dot x & = x(1-y) \\
\dot y & = x y
\end{align}
This equation has fixed points along the y-axis $(0,y^*)$

Comment: When I show two values for the CP, it means the third can be anything, so yes, for example, the second CP I show is $$(x, y, z) = (x, 0, 0)$$ Substitute those two values into each of the 3-equations. Clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation $(2)$ gives
$$
y^* = 0\, , \qquad\text{or}\qquad x^* = \frac{\gamma+\eta\epsilon}{\beta}
$$
at equilibrium. Injecting these two possibilities in equation $(3)$ yields either
$$
z^* = 0 \quad\text{or}\quad x^* = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\, , \qquad\text{or}\qquad z^* = \frac{\epsilon\eta\phi\, y^*}{\alpha-\gamma-\eta\epsilon} .
$$
Now, we use $(1)$ at equilibrium:

- the case $y^* = 0 = z^*$ gives $x^* \in \mathbb{R}$. There is an equilibrium line;
- the case $y^* = 0$, $x^* = {\alpha}/{\beta}$ gives $z^* \in \mathbb{R}$. There is a second equilibrium line;
- the case $x^* = ({\gamma+\eta\epsilon})/{\beta}$, $z^* = {\epsilon\eta\phi\, y^*}/({\alpha-\gamma-\eta\epsilon})$ gives $y^*=0=z^*$.

The last equilibrium point is conditioned by $\alpha \neq \gamma + \eta\epsilon$, which was already assumed when writing $z^* = {\epsilon\eta\phi\, y^*}/({\alpha-\gamma-\eta\epsilon})$. This equilibrium point belongs to the first equilibrium line, and is therefore not isolated.

Comment: Thank you!, in the third case doesn't $y^*=0$ then mean that $z^*=0$ too?

Comment: @AngusTheMan Yes, that's it!